# Is it possible to limit in a JTextField the area where characters can be inserted?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I've a JTextField with a JButton positioned inside of it on the east side. At the moment, when characters inserted reach the button the part of the text overlapping is inserted below of it.

Here a snippet to reproduce the problem

```
class TextFieldWithIconLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextField modelFileTField = new JTextField();
        modelFileTField.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton("click");
        button.addActionListener(listener -> System.err.println("clicked!"));
        modelFileTField.add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(200, 100);
        frame.add(modelFileTField);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

These, instead, are screenshots of the real situation

[image: Short text]

[image: Long text]

I would like to avoid text overlapping with button without limiting the number of characters user can insert.

PS: If I add the JTextField and the JButton in a JPanel it works like a charm but I have some limitations and this approach at the moment isn't feasible unfortunately

Comment: I don't understand: you think you'll have a button inside your textfield?

Comment: I have a JTextField with inside a JButton. See the code snippet

Comment: faintly remember that we used (in SwingX) a custom border containing the extra component and/or a custom layout to place everything correctly .. so it might not be entirely trivial, forgot the dirty details ;)

Comment: Check out the [Component Border](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/component-border/) which does what you want. *I have some limitations and this approach at the moment isn't feasible unfortunately* - what limitations? Why isn't it feasable?

Comment: @camickr Thank you for your suggestion, I'll give it a try! However I'm working on a Swing library used in my company, so there're restrictions. Obviously those could be changed but... not now, this is a fix for a release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved using FlatLaf Look and Feel (https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/). In this way setting a specific property on the JTextField text and icon aren't overlapping anymore.
Specifically I did:

```
class TextFieldWithIconLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton("click");
        button.addActionListener(listener -> System.err.println("clicked!"));
        textField.add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);

        //Property to set
        textField.putClientProperty(FlatClientProperties.TEXT_FIELD_TRAILING_COMPONENT, button);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(200, 100);
        frame.add(modelFileTField);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```